# Timeout while deploying chaincode in hyperledger fabric

Tags: node.js, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

Getting this message in my docker container, when I try to deploy my chaincode from a node.js file

[dockercontroller] Start -> DEBU 0a1 start-could not find image ...attempt to recreate image no such image
vp_1          | 18:49:40.460 [eventhub_producer] deRegisterHandler -> DEBU 0a2 deRegisterHandler BLOCK
vp_1          | 18:49:40.515 [eventhub_producer] Chat -> ERRO 0a3 Error during Chat, stopping handler: stream error: code = 1 desc = "context canceled"

Comment: Response in terminal                                                                                                                                                                                                          Deploying chaincode now...
ERROR: Failed to deploy chaincode: request={"chaincodePath":"sample","fcn":"init","args":["hi there"]}, error="timed out waiting for transaction to complete"
Exiting and disconnecting eventHub channel.

Comment: did you ever figure out the reason?

Comment: @alihaider probably some bug in v0.6 of the Fabric, coudn't figure though particularly, work around was tried to write a new chaincode and it worked correctly, though at time it gets Killed while deploying